# Pass and persist variables to next page - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cookies

Fairly new to AngularJS and looking for guidance. Below is my setup;

```
www.page1.php?variable1=one&variable2=two&variable3=three
www.page2.php
```

I want to take the 3 variables from `page1.php` url and pass them to `page2.php` when a button is pressed.
I also want to persist these somehow as the `page3.php` , `page4.php` etc will need them. The pages utilise AngularJS to make use of the variables.

I know there're a couple of ways to do this;

1. cookies;
   I can access the variables using `$_GET`, how can I save them as cookies? with Angular?
2. localStorage;
   How can I access url parameters, save them as a `var` and add to local storage like `localStorage["variable"] = variablefromurl;`

Which way is the best?
Any guidance will be appreciated. I'm new to Angular.

FYI this is for a shopping cart..

Unrelated question; What is the best way to save a Cart client-side?

```
$_SESSIONS(PHP)? $_COOKIES(PHP or AngularJS)? localStorage(AngularJS)?
```

Comment: to save a singleton(e.g. cart in your case) you can use `service` methods which keep your cart updated. 
or 
rather crude/unrecommended way of doing it will be using a variable inside `$rootScope`

Comment: Can you give a quick code example of using an Angular `service` please

Answer (score 0):

For sharing information between different pages you can use `$stateParams` and you can refer [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) link for more explanation.

For services you can refer original documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)